# Парсинг сайтов через CURL - как все таки сделать правильно?

Tags: php, curl, прокси

Имеется простая потребность в парсинге сайтов для анализа цен. Схема простая: вручную вводятся урлы в базу, цены ищутся регуляркой в коде страницы. А вот написанием скрипта для парсинга у меня имеются проблемы, которые по мере написания становятся все сложнее... Поэтому возникает вопрос, **как должен быть устроен Парсер сайтов, как он должен работать, по какой схеме?**

Расскажу свой процесс написания скрипта и расскажу об возникших проблемах:

1. Парсер работает по-простому через однопоточный CURL. Пока так, многопоточность в принципе и не нужна, так как между запросами к одному сайту должны быть интервалы секунд так в 60, чтобы не выделяться.
2. Логично, что со своего сервера парсить не получится, или получится но недолго - забанят сайты, к которым идет доступ. Значит надо использовать прокси.
3. Купил платный доступ к сервису дающему список рабочих прокси, список загружается каждый раз в начале скрипта. Проблема: часто прокси дохлые, выдают для рабочих сайтов и урлов код ответа 0, хотя сервис-список прокси показывает, что они рабочие с большим аптаймом. Решение: сначала проверять прокси. Проверка делается путем доступа к общедоступным сайтам типа Яндекс, Гугл.
4. В скрипте анализаторе цен стоит анализатор URL, если давать ему неправильные URL, они удаляются из массива и далее из базы данных. Фильтрация осуществляется через filter_var( $url , FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ). Проблема: кривой менеджер мог забить в базу данных с виду валидный урл, но нерабочий (например, обрезать каике-то последние символы). Решение: смотреть коды ответа сервера при доступе по URL'у. Если 404 - аналогично удалять урл. И вот на этом шаге возникает уйма проблем...
5. Очень много прокси работают через раз и вообще непонятно как. Даже после отсеивания явно неработающих прокси (п.3), остается куча стремных прокси (у меня даже ощущение что не бывает нормальных прокси, никто не станет их делать бесплатно, поэтому они все только стремные). В чем стремность: они работают через раз. Проблема: Для десяти стопроцентно работающих сайтов и урлов прокси могут выдавать вообще любые коды ответа: 302, 401, 403, 407, 504 - все что угодно. Решение: решение я придумал кривое, если выдается ошибка 404 - парсинг напрямую с сервера (это плохо, но если брать другое прокси как понять что оно вменяемое и не выдает ошибку само по себе?), если любая другая - берется другой прокси. Количество ошибок для прокси, конечно, сохраняется и они удаляются при доcтижении како-то порога.
6. Все вроде бы работало хорошо, но потом посыпались ошибки. Я долго разбирался и выяснил, что одно прокси отдавало код страницы без кавычек (!). К проблемам с прокси добавилась еще одна, а сколько их еще потенциально может быть?
7. И это не все, в процессе выяснилось, что один сайт работает на CloudFlare и не парсится вообще, требует пройти проверку от роботов. Теоретически можно сделать, чтобы выводилась капча и вручную вводить, но не для 50 же прокси...
8. Также в процессе один сайт что-то изменил в настройках, в результате его перестали открывать все прокси, заходы напрямую с сервера тоже были заблокированы.

В общем, я в тупике. При работе с проксями возникает куча проблем из-за странной их работы, некоторые я решил, как решать остальные не знаю. Подскажите верный алгоритм работы, библиотеку, что-нибудь. Или может быть нужен вообще какой-то другой подход к работе?

Comment: Попиарю-ка я свою [библиотеку](https://github.com/hindmost/rolling-curl-mini).

Comment: Прочитал по диагонали. И как понял библиотека дает многопоточность, но не решает указанных проблем. Как дела с репарсингом? "Конченные" прокси не убираются и используются все время работы скрипта? "Битое" ли содержимое выдало прокси никак не проверяется?

Comment: _Прочитал по диагонали. И как понял библиотека дает многопоточность, но не решает указанных проблем..._ Видно, что по диагонали и не до конца. Во [2-й части](http://savreen.com/mnogopotochnyj-sbor-dannyx-s-ispolzovaniem-cepochek-svyazannyx-curl-zaprosov-chast-2/) рассматриваются, как прокси, так и репарсинг (повторный парсинг), и даже обработка cookies. Читайте внимательно, в т.ч. комментарии.

Comment: У меня 2 вопроса написанные выше есть, как с этим-то дело обстоит? Никак?

Comment: Вы напрасно ждете полное решение ваших проблем - в комментариях вы его точно не получите. Я показал вам общие рекомендации и пример кода. А дальше уж сами.

Answer (score 1):

> вручную вводятся урлы в базу, цены ищутся регуляркой в коде страницы

Я так понимаю, нужно парсить какие то определённые сайты. 
Можно брать по порядку, как вы и делаете. Но, лучше было бы ставить задачи в очередь, например rabbitMQ. Задавать количество попыток, например 5. Http-Код != 200 - отправляем задачу на след. попытку. Но, если страниц для парсинга не слишком много - можно и не усложнять.

> Решение: смотреть коды ответа сервера при доступе по URL'у. Если 404 -
>   аналогично удалять урл. И вот на этом шаге возникает уйма проблем...

Думаю, при 404, нужно не боясь удалять url. Только делать это на последней попытке.

Я бы делал прямые запросы, пока сайты не банят. У большинства мелких магазинов (не считая тех, которые всегда хостятся у продавца - пр. nethouse.ru, т.е. там куча магазинов на одном сервере) нет никакой защиты от ботов. А access-логи никто не смотрит.
В заголовки подставлять всегда валидный User-Agent. Лучше забить в базу пару сотен или тысяч юзер-агентов и рандомно брать любой из них. Взять можно здесь http://www.useragentstring.com/. Если UA будут отличаться от запроса к запросу - не страшно. Также и др. заголовки ставить ('Accept-Charset', 'Accept-Encoding' и др.), которые всегда ставит браузер.

**Также лучше разделить сайты на группы - что через какие прокси парсить, а что напрямую.** (например, nethouse нет смысла парсить через tor).

**Бесплатные proxy**
они очень часто глюченные. Речь про те, списки которых (host, port) можно скачать в интернете.

Могу посоветовать tor-proxy https://www.torproject.org/. Это SOCKS5 бесплатный proxy, запускается как демон. Ip можно менять хоть каждую секунду, посылая сигнал демону. Подбирать рабочие ip tor будет сам. Могу сказать, что более 95% запросов - успешно отправляются. Tor к глюченным нельзя отнести.

Некоторые сайты закрыты от тора, тот же nethouse и CloudFlare. Поэтому nethouse парсить напрямую (я ежедневно паршу пару магазинов nethouse напрямую, делая запрос раз в секунду - до сих пор не забанили).

С CloudFlare беда, очень хорошо банят. Тут в любом случае придётся платить за нормальный proxy или искать способы отправлять запросы с "нормальных" ip.